# jQuery show/hide for multiple elements without specific classes / id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML and JS Code to show / hide a div. At the moment it is working fine. But I would like to use more than one Box on a page and so i need to have a function to know which box-header was clicked.

Is it possible to trigger only the box-content div after the box-header div which was clicked? It would be great if I don't have to use specific id's for every box.

Here is my Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="content-box">
    <div class="box-header open-close">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box-content").hide();

    $(".open-close").click(function () {
        $(".box-content").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the `box-content` element in relation to the clicked `open-close` element.

From the given markup, it is the next element of the clicked element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box-content").hide();

    $(".open-close").click(function () {
        //as @insertusernamehere said the selector ".box-content" is not required
        //$(this).next(".box-content").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Huvak/)

Comment: If the content is always the next element to its header you can optionally remove the selector: `$(this).next().slideToggle('slow');`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box-content").hide();

    $(".open-close").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".box-content").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```